# How to set default port on MySQL for Mac

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

On OSX when I try to use the following:

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.dbname = "myDb"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
```

I get the following error

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Library/WebServer/sites/testweb/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 129

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Library/WebServer/sites/testweb/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129
Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/sites/testweb/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=gl...', 'myDb', '', Array)
#1 /Library/WebServer/sites/testweb/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#2 /Library/WebServer/sites/testweb/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(858): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /Library/WebServer/sites/testweb/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(928): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote('asdf@asd...', NULL)
#4 /Library/WebServer/sites/testweb/library/Zend/Db/Select.php(1000): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quoteInto('email = ?', 'asdf@asd...', NULL)
#5 /Library/WebServer/sites/testweb/library/Zen in /Library/WebServer/sites/testweb/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144
```

If I add :3306 then it works

```
resources.db.params.host = "localhost:3306"
```

However then windows machines have problems connecting like that.

Is there a way to have OSX connect on just localhost mysql default port?

Comment: check out this link: http://www.comentum.com/mysql-administration.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use 'localhost' as an ip instead of having unix systems attempting to connect to the socket, simply provide the ip-address instead of 'localhost' - 127.0.0.1

```
resources.db.params.host = 127.0.0.1
```

To specify the port, you should use the separate line in your resource configuration if necessary:

```
resources.db.params.port = 3306
```

Comment: +1 as I had the exact problem with linux and this was the solutions for me. It would be nice if rschmitty would let us know if this worked for him on his mac.

Comment: I did have the same issue on my macbook and I can confirm that using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost is properly working now.

Answer (score 5):

Mountain Lion with `MAMP` solution:

`sudo ln -f /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php /usr/bin/php`